# wp-cli is not working properly. No response from commands

Tags: multisite, wp-cli

I am trying to make a copy of a live site on a test server. I installed wp-cli and wp-cli sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. When it doesn't work, it just returns nothing. Not one character of output. I can view the website, apache, php and mysql all seem to be working. I turned on `WP_DEBUG` in `wp-config.php` and I see a couple of minor errors, as follows:

> PHP Notice:  wpdb::escape is **deprecated** since version
>   3.6! Use wpdb::prepare() or esc_sql() instead. in /var/www/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3083 Notice: wpdb::escape
>   is **deprecated** since version 3.6! Use wpdb::prepare()
>   or esc_sql() instead. in /var/www/wp-includes/functions.php on line
>   3083

I have tried `wp-cli --debug`

The only command that works is `wp-cli --info`

This is the output of `wp-cli`, in case that is helpful.

PHP binary: `/usr/bin/php5‌‌`
PHP version: 5.5.3-1ubuntu2.3
php.ini used: `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`
WP-CLI root dir: `phar://wp-cli.phar`
WP-CLI global config:
WP-CLI project config:
WP-CLI version: 0.15.0

Every once in a while, a command will work. This is very strange.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using Wordpress multi-site.

Comment: This method isn't used by WP core or wp-cli either. It must be coming from somewhere else.

Comment: I also have this problem - wp --info and wp --debug get me something, but all other commands are failing silently. Not using a multisite.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the --url flag when you have a multisite.

```
wp-cli --debug --url=www.example.com
```

or

```
wp theme list --url=www.example.com
```

Comment: See also https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/730

Answer (score 0):

If you only installed php5-cli then you probably don't have php5-mysql. Try running `sudo apt-get install php5-mysql` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on a single-site install. Turned out that I had a broken plugin, and that was causing the site itself to fail with a fatal error.

Once I replaced the broken plugin and the fatal error went away, wp-cli worked as normal.

Answer (score 0):

It can happen when you have malware in your installation.

Check the `wp-config.php` file for signs of malware.